# Xcode Swift Package Manager error - The repository could not be found

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I can't find any SO questions regarding this, but I've run into this problem twice. Basically when I'm trying to add a new package via SPM, I sometimes get the following error:

```
The repository could not be found. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and try again.
```

For example, I'm trying to get PanModal (https://github.com/slackhq/PanModal) and I get the following:

[image]

What's especially interesting is that while Xcode claims that the repo is not found, it *can* discover its version on the previous screen:

[image]

What can be wrong here? Arguably PanModal just got SPM support, but that's 15 hours ago and I think that should be enough. Also iiuc SPM is decentralized so there shouldn't be cache or registry stuff that's in the way?

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem for me today..

Comment: Update: fwiw the PanModal package starts to work after ~4 days, with no change in the repo whatsoever.

Comment: I ran into this today. Cleaning out derived data solved the issue.

Answer (score 27):

I had to disable HTTPS to SSH rewriting for Git.

Check inside your `~/.gitconfig` file if you have some line such as:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

If so comment it or remove when adding Swift Package Manager dependencies.

Comment: still necessary?

Comment: Only thing that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

clean DerivedData and add Package again

```sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Comment: Can OP mark this as solution please?

Comment: Funnily enough, this is what caused the error for me in the first place. Reset Package Caches fixed it.

Comment: This did NOT work for me (it won't work for all situations). I have used similar successfully at other times.

Answer (score 17):

When this happened in Xcode 13.3, I just had to trigger the Reset Package Caches action in the Packages menu.

[image: Xcode Reset Package Caches]

Answer (score 8):

For me, I just had to relaunch Xcode ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: Couldn't believe it, but also, that was what did the trick for me. Sure wish I could get those 2 hours back.

Answer (score 5):

None of the previous answers worked for me. Instead I switched to XCode beta (currently version 15), and that seems to have cleared the issue up. It's not the first time I've had to switch to the beta (and back again when that broke).

Comment: this solution works for me. switch to 15.0 beta 1, add dependency then back to 14.3.1

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to encounter the error when cloning for private Swift Packages. Log in with your GitHub account to authenticate Xcode when fetching the packages.

**Note:** We don't need SSH keys for authentication.

`~/.netrc` contents:

```
machine api.github.com
login <Insert GitHub Username here>
password <Insert GH Personal Access Token here>
```

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd ~`
3. `touch .netrc` to create the .netrc file
4. `open .netrc`
5. Copy and Paste the contents above
6. Save the file
7. Close Xcode
8. Clear the DerivedData folder
9. Re-open Xcode

Answer (score 0):

An addition to `EBDOKUM`'s answer: Reopening Xcode works sometimes, but not always.
Opening the project using the `.xcproject` or `xcworkspace` may/may not fix package errors. Alternatively, something that worked extremely well for me was opening the XCode app, and opening the file using the "Open a project or file" option:

[image]