# Xcode SPM, Firebase iOS SDK: The remote repository could not be accessed, invalid credentials

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I have never come across this error before using Swift Package Manager and Xcode.

I'm using Xcode 14.3.1, trying to add Firebase iOS SDK.

Other SDKs add fine via Swift Package Manager. It's only firebase-ios-sdk that's giving me issues.

I've tried [cleaning derived data and resetting package caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62827921/10467554), that hasn't changed anything. I'm properly logged into Github and iCloud.

What could this issue be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Xcode beta was outdated, and I needed to download Xcode 15.0 beta 3.

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11556) is the full conversation that solved my issue.